# Boot problems with Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I have Windows XP on my C drive and Windows 7 on D drive. I loaded Ubuntu 14.04 over Windows 7 on D. It gives me my old boot screen of either Windows XP or Windows 7, and it will not boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: This should have your answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/88432

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have an Ubuntu Live CD with you, you can proceed with the following option:

[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)